# Ruby pattern for access particular fields of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I'm coding in ruby and want to ask about a possible pattern(or maybe even a gem)

My issue is I have 2 classes

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
class User < ApplicationRecord
```

I want to be able to map Review fields in a way that a user(of a particular type) can access only some fields.

What first comes to mind would be to have a `global` get method something like

```
def self.fields_for(user:)
 if user.admin?
   [:name, :created_by].join(",")
 else
   ...
 end
end
```

and then

```
Review.where(...).pluck(Review.fields_for(user: user))
```

but this seems a bit clumsy and difficult to scale. Could you suggest a better away?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may be good and scale, but others programmers thought about that same problem before, and there are a few tools you can use that are well tested and in constant maintenance.

For this, I suggest you to investigate about the [Policy Object Pattern](https://makandracards.com/alexander-m/43084-policy-objects), which is used this way:

```
class ReviewPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :fields

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
    @fields = determine_fields
  end

  private

  def determine_fields
    if user.admin?
      [:name, :created_by]
    else
      # Other fields for different roles
    end
  end
end

# Usage
policy = ReviewPolicy.new(user)
Review.select(*policy.fields).where(...)
```

Or by Pundit Gem as:

```
class ReviewPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all.select(:name, :created_by)
      else
        # Different scope for other users
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With Pundit you define a scope in your policy to control which fields are selected from the database.